# Andorid Studio 2.0 Preview 5 Error during launch

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-2.0

the error log goes to

```
Error installing split apks: com.android.ddmlib.InstallException: Failed to finalize session : -26: Package here.is.packagename new target SDK 22 doesn't support runtime permissions but the old target SDK 23 does.
```

update project build.gradle `targetSdkVersion = 23` will solve the error, but I don`t know why?

Comment: Plz remove code about runtime permissions.

Answer (score 12):

You can't downgrade from an app using `targetSdkVersion` 23 to one using an older `targetSdkVersion`, as the error says.

Instead, you must fully uninstall the `targetSdkVersion=23` version of the app from the device. After that, you'll be able to install the app targeting an older version of Android.

Comment: did you read this though (new target SDK 22 doesn't support runtime permissions but the old target SDK 23 does) it thinks 23 is older than 22, unless  im reading that wrong

Comment: @Tasos 'new target SDK 22' is what his app is now targeting. 'old target SDK 23' is what is currently installed.

Comment: @Tasos - this has nothing to do with what is downloaded or not. It *should* probably prompt to uninstall the current app entirely as that is the only way to recover from this case.

Comment: yeah youre right -- i just checked one of my gradles, it will only prompt you if you havent got the builds tools installed -- eg (compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1")